# How to fit all the elements to JFrame screen in my conditions

Tags: java, jframe, size, screen, element

Today I made an app which contains alot of elements such as jpanels , jbuttons etc...

Now I tried this app in another PC and I saw that all the positions and sizes of the elements have changed as I wanted.

When I say "I wanted." I mean that In my PC Which i made the app , Basically I positioned all the elements to Screen size - 1024*728.

and When I tested the app in another PC (Screen size - 1920*1020) as I said the positions and sizes of the elements have changed.

How Can I manage to fit all the positions of the elements and sizes to how I want it in the 1024*728 screen resolution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing the code you are using to lay out your components, your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Just a simple code really , I'm just adding all the elements to the JFrame. I can't show the code because it's really long. (I'm adding the elements with a specific location like setLocation)

Comment: And that is the important information we needed.  Use a LayoutManager instead.  Different computers will use different font faces and sizes, so you cannot safely assume your components will have the same size as they do on your computer.